# clickhouse downsample into OHLC time bar intervals

Tags: group-by, clickhouse, yandex

For a table e.g. containing a date, price timeseries with prices every e.g. millisecond, how can this be downsampled into groups of open high low close (ohlc) rows with time interval e.g. minute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While option with arrays will work, the simplest option here is to use use combination of group by timeintervals with `min`, `max`, `argMin`, `argMax` aggregate functions.

```sql
SELECT 
  id,
  minute,
  max(value) AS high,
  min(value) AS low,
  avg(value) AS avg,
  argMin(value, timestamp) AS first,
  argMax(value, timestamp) AS last
FROM security
GROUP BY id, toStartOfMinute(timestamp) AS minute
ORDER BY minute
```

Comment: I agree.  This is a better solution.  Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 3):

In ClickHouse you solve this kind of problem with arrays. Let's assume a table like the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE security (
  timestamp DateTime,
  id UInt32,
  value Float32
)
ENGINE=MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(timestamp)
ORDER BY (id, timestamp)
```

You can downsample to one-minute intervals with a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT 
  id, minute, max(value) AS high, min(value) AS low, avg(value) AS avg,
  arrayElement(arraySort((x,y)->y, 
    groupArray(value), groupArray(timestamp)), 1) AS first,
  arrayElement(arraySort((x,y)->y, 
    groupArray(value), groupArray(timestamp)), -1) AS last
FROM security
GROUP BY id, toStartOfMinute(timestamp) AS minute
ORDER BY minute
```

The trick is to use array functions.  Here's how to decode the calls:

1. [groupArray](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#agg_function-grouparray) gathers column data within the group into an array.
2. [arraySort](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/array_functions/#array_functions-sort) sorts the values using the timestamp order.  We use a lambda function to provide the timestamp array as the sorting key for the first array of values.
3. [arrayElement](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/array_functions/#arrayelement-arr-n-operator-arr-n) allows us to pick the first and last elements respectively.

To keep the example simple I used DateTime for the timestamp which only samples at 1 second intervals.  You can use a UInt64 column to get any precision you want.  I added an average to my query to help check results.