# Clickhouse downsample into OHLC different time bar intervals

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-go

How would you do all kinds of time frames especially time frames where you have gaps in time over 24hr?  Like accounting for close/swap on 24hr currency markets or commodities / indexes ?

[clickhouse downsample into OHLC time bar intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698667/clickhouse-downsample-into-ohlc-time-bar-intervals/62394710?noredirect=1#comment110358434_62394710) on stackoverflow

Shows how to do 1 minute but does not show how to-do different time frames or deal with swap / close time during 24hr.

How would one go about using time in golang with clickhouse so time.Time from golang could be used in clickhouse date where clause ?

Comment: To define the arbitrary interval use [toStartOfInterval](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#tostartofintervaltime-or-data-interval-x-unit-time-zone)-function.

Comment: could you provide examples for close/swap, etc. cases (the origin data and required result)?